# MySQL Stored Procedure basics

Tags: mysql

This looks like a pretty rudimentary question but for someone who is new to MySQL, it has proven to be a tough nut to crack.

I've been trying to create a stored procedure in the MySQL and this is what I tried:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test_procedure`(
    IN dtst_nm varchar(42)
)
BEGIN 
    SELECT 
        COUNT(*) 
    FROM 
        data_hub.dtst_nm 
    ;
END
```

When I run this, I get the error that dtst_nm doesn't exist. The exact error message is:

```
"Error Code: 1146. Table 'data_hub.dtst_nm' doesn't exist"
```

Clearly the variable is not getting resolved.

From what I gathered, the syntax seems to be right. What am I missing?

Comment: Please provide the exact error message you get from MySQl

Comment: Already mentioned in the original post. "dtst_nm doesn't exist." Please read before you comment/downvote.

Comment: I have not downvoted; but your tone does not make a friendly gesture to someone who is trying to help!

Comment: Sorry for the tone but I already wrote. The OP is less than three lines. How can you not read that? There is only one variable in the snippet and I mentioned verbosely that that variable is not being resolved.

Comment: MySQL does not give just three words as an error message. It gives out a lot more details. Nevertheless based on your **limited** error message, I have given an answer. Try that

Comment: "Error Code: 1146. Table 'data_hub.dtst_nm' doesn't exist" - That's the exact error message.

Comment: Ok got it. You are trying to use the input variable as table name. This is a Dynamic SQL problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [Dynamic SQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) problem. You cannot directly specify variables in place of table and column names. You will need to use string functions of create SQL query string. Then use `Prepare` with `Execute` to run the query.

Try:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test_procedure` $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test_procedure`(
    IN `dtst_nm` varchar(42)
)
BEGIN 

  SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ', dtst_nm );
  PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: 1) Why do we need to use DELIMITER $$? As long as there is no conflict, I can skip that. Correct?
2) Is the second line important? For just learning/testing, it seems to be optional. Correct?
3) The solution still didn't work for me. If I run the query (select count(*) from data_hub.datahub_clients) directly, I get the output right.

Comment: @SushantVasishta you mean `Drop procedure ..` ?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I pressed enter too soon; much before my query could be completed. Have added more details to my comment.

Comment: @SushantVasishta 1) Redefining delimiter to something else is a good practice. Eg: PHPMyAdmin will throw error if you dont do it, as its parser will execute at every semicolon, which we dont want. 2) Second line is optional, but it helps in avoiding error message when a duplicate SP already exists. 3) In your SP you are not returning the results. put your select query results to some variable and then using `INOUT` type, return it from your SP

Comment: I am working on MySQL workbench and I get syntax error at the first statement (DELIMITER $$) - is not valid input at this position. When I moved it down, the error changed to 'missing colon'. I got the idea behind the delimiter change and I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Thanks. I had to remove the delimiter statements and it worked fine.